# If $E$ is a subset of $X$, then $E$ is open if and only if the complement $X\backslash E = \{x\in X\mid x\not\in E\}$ is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

If $E$ is a subset of $X$, then $E$ is open if and only if the complement $X\backslash E = \{x\in X\mid x\not\in E\}$ is closed.

**MY ATTEMPT**

> Let us prove the implication $(\Rightarrow)$ first.

If $E$ is open, then $E = \text{int}(E)$.

Since $X = \text{int}(E)\cup\partial E\cup\text{ext}(E)$ is partition of $X$, we conclude that

$$E^{c} = \partial E\cup\text{ext}(E) = \partial E^{c}\cup\text{int}(E^{c}) = \overline{E^{c}}$$

which is closed because it contains all its adherent points.

> We may tackle the converse implication $(\Leftarrow)$ now.

If $E^{c}$ is closed, then $E^{c}\supseteq \partial E^{c} = \partial E$. Then we have that $\partial E\cap E^{c} = \partial E$. Consequently, we have that
\begin{align*}
E\cap\partial E = E\cap(\partial E\cap E^{c}) = (E\cap E^{c})\cap\partial E = \varnothing\cap \partial E = \varnothing \Rightarrow E\cap \partial E = \varnothing
\end{align*}
Thus $E$ is open, and we are done.

**Comments on the definitions and results**

We say that $E$ is open if $E\cap\partial E = \varnothing$. We do also say that $E$ is closed when $\partial E\subseteq E$.

It also has been proved that $\overline{E} = \text{int}(E)\cup\partial E$.

Comment: How do you define a closed set? A typical definition is that the closed sets are the complements of open sets.

Comment: The first definition says that $E$ is closed if $E\supseteq\partial E$. It also has been proven that $E$ is closed iff it contains all its adherent points.

Comment: I mean the closure of the complement. Thanks for the comment. I'll fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've misused the given relation. I'll try to fix it.